# Install TPTP profile tool

Tags: java, eclipse-tptp

I have installed the TPTP tool according to the instruction.
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Install_TPTP_with_Update_Manager

After the restart I still cannot find the TPTP profile button. how to enable it?

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using ?

Comment: Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse TPTP is obsolete for Higher version of Eclipse, It only supports up to Helios and Galileo version of Eclipse. Besides TPTP is also not available in Eclipse Market place.

Probably, this link may be helpful to you.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Profiling_with_TPTP_-_plug-in_development

Comment: if it is no longer available, what is the alternative?

Comment: You can use JDK VisualVM for testing.